# Is there a way of creating a design in LaTeX the same way CSS allows you to style a HTML page?

Tags: packages, document-classes, book-design

As you probably know, CSS isn't only there to make text red or to tell the browser you don't want your links to be underlined: CSS is an incredibly powerful designing tool that allows you to shift and reposition every element in your document wherever you want—but, most importantly, it works in combination with the basic `<div>` element to create a standard, raw rectangular box that can be used for whatever purpose you want.

For example, you can divide your page in two boxes placed one next to another if you want to have text in two columns; you can give a paragraph a fancy box to stay in that you can color the way you want (both its inside and its border); you can even make the box's width a single pixel so to simulate a vertical line that you can again style freely. You can imitate pretty much any design you want just by dividing everything in boxes and then moving them accordingly—making some of them transparent, making them thin or large, coloring them black or another color and so on.

Therefore, my question is: **what class or package do I use that allows me the same level of control as CSS?** The context is that I'm writing a book about mathematics, and I have all the ideal design choices in mind but I can't replicate them in LaTeX the way I can with CSS. I don't even know how to draw a simple box around a definition or a theorem, for instance, let alone being able to position a chapter's number or title in a corner of the page.

But there has to be a way to do it, right?

Comment: If you wan't to control finer aspects of your document, Plain or ConTeXt are probably better. LaTeX is a bit "rigid", so to say.

Comment: @JairoA.delRio certainly in the case of plain it would be much harder to do almost anything (eg use accented letters or cross references or ....) styling latex is certainly easier than making a usable document format on top of plain and styling that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So ConTeXt remains. Maybe I got things wrong, but LaTeX is better with templates (theses and papers, for instance), whereas ConTeXt is better for customization IMO.

Comment: while it's true it is fairly easy to style a bare `<div>` with css the issues with styling existing latex constructs like theorems are merging in to an existing design, so perhaps a better comparison is adding css to style a specific item in a web page such as this site where the existing layout is already a mix of existing css and generated html from javascrript so getting the timing and specificity right for your CSS can be "interesting"

Comment: @JairoA.delRio I'm not sure I'd agree but I know latex a_lot_ better than context having being on the team maintaining it for over 25 years, so not exactly an impartial judge:-)

Comment: @David Carlisle So what I need is some form of "empty" LaTeX that doesn't come with any specific default style, right? And is this ConTeXt something like that?

Comment: You might want to look at the LaTeX `memoir` class (`> texdoc memoir`) which provides many means of designing your document. I don't know about CSS but from what you describe it is concerned with the graphical layout whereas LaTeX tries to keep the semantic ideas and then display them in various ways; it understands the concept of "chapter" and provides means for you to display the title however you want.

Comment: regarding the boxes: check the tcolorbox package